# Spinner populated from SQLite DataBase with empty selection

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a spinner with empty selection, but the problem is that i'm loading my spinner from SQLite DataBase. Here's code I'm using to load the spinner:

```
 public void loadSpinnerDataRegion() {
       DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

            try {

                myDbHelper.createDataBase();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                throw new Error("Unable to create database");

            }

            try {

                myDbHelper.openDataBase();


            }catch(SQLException sqle){

                throw sqle;

            } 

            // Spinner Drop down elements

            RegionList=myDbHelper.getAllRegion();
             // Creating adapter for spinner
             ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,RegionList);
              // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // attaching data adapter to spinner
                spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter); 
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RegionList.add("");
ArrayList<String> list= myDbHelper.getAllRegion();
RegionList.addAll(list);

 ArrayAdapter<String>dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,RegionList);
```

Answer (score 1):

to make the spinner empty call `dataAdapter.clear();`

then fill it again when you need; like this:

```
dataAdapter.addAll(RegionList);
```

or you can make iteration over the whole array, and add each element seperately, like this:

```
for (Object object: RegionList) {
            dataAdapter.add(object.getData());
        }
```

hope this was helpful answer

Comment: i tried the first one dataAdapter.clear(); dataAdapter.addAll(RegionList); it don't fill the spinner again, it just empty it

Comment: try to add each element separately in a for loop, like above

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it:
    RegionList=myDbHelper.getAllRegion();
        RegionList.add(0, "");
         // Creating adapter for spinner
         ArrayAdapterdataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,RegionList);
Thank you all!!